# How to control a SparkApplication programatically using the python kubernetes client?

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I'd like to submit a [SparkApplication](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/) to a Kubernetes cluster programmatically from python.

A job definition `job.yaml` like this

```
apiVersion: sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: my-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  sparkVersion: "2.4.0"
  type: Python
...
```

runs without problems using `kubectl apply -f job.yaml`, but I cannot figure  out whether and how I can use the [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to start this job programmatically.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example mentioned, how to create third party resource on kubernetes using kubernetes python client.

> https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/create_thirdparty_resource.md

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but third party resources were retired (the example actually does not work), and superseded by custom resource definitions - which I tried to use, but had no idea of how to make it work in my example

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import kubernetes.client
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# Configure API key authorization: BearerToken
configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
# Uncomment below to setup prefix (e.g. Bearer) for API key, if needed
# configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = kubernetes.client.CustomObjectsApi(kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration))
group = 'group_example' # str | The custom resource's group name
version = 'version_example' # str | The custom resource's version
namespace = 'namespace_example' # str | The custom resource's namespace
plural = 'plural_example' # str | The custom resource's plural name. For TPRs this would be lowercase plural kind.
body = NULL # object | The JSON schema of the Resource to create.
pretty = 'pretty_example' # str | If 'true', then the output is pretty printed. (optional)

try: 
    api_response = api_instance.create_namespaced_custom_object(group, version, namespace, plural, body, pretty=pretty)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling CustomObjectsApi->create_namespaced_custom_object: %s\n" % e)
```

source https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md#create_namespaced_custom_object